# opencv3.1.0 programming In Qt5.5.1: error: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_4'

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

everyone, I am compiling a little opencv programme with Qt5.5.1 in ubuntu14.04, but there are some troubles.
First I made a Qt Widgets Application, The  main.cpp codes are as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat srcImage = imread("lena.jpg");
    imshow("orig", srcImage);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

And the show.pro codes are:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-10-20T19:22:57
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = show
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

When I contruct the project ,here are the errors:

```
/home/lmk/keke/build-show-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/main.o:-1: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:681: error: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_4'
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Are you using OpenCV compiled with GCC 32 bit? Are you using debug libs in debug, and release libs in release?

Comment: Yes, I compiled with GCC 32 bit, the path is `/home/newdisk/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc`, and for your second question, I think just as you say. It seems that I just use the debug model.@Miki

Comment: Maybe I've got one solution: add one line to my `show.pro` file: `LIBS += /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatomic.so.1`
I have tried, and there exists no error.@Miki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I've got one solution: add one line to my show.pro file, just as follows

```
LIBS += /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatomic.so.1
```

I have tried, and there exists no error.@Miki